# Screen navigates to Signin screen when I press Signup button in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've a Sign up Screen with text fields of username, fullname, email, password and a **Sign up** Button. And at the bottom of Sign up screen I've a 
**Already have a Account? Sign in**

Now, if I fill my sign up details and press on Sign up button, it navigates back me to the Sign in screen. Sign up button should navigate me to the HomeScreen.

But if I remove - **Already have a Account? Sign in** from my Sign up Screen, then sign up button successfully navigates to the HomeScreen.

I don't know why this would happen even though my code if perfectly fine. 
Also, by any chance could this be an issue of SoftKeyboard overlapping?

```
// Below is my Signup Screen 

export default class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     fullname: '',
     username: '',
     email: '',
     password: '',
     confirm_password: '',
    };
  }


  signupCall = () => {
       fetch(strings.baseUri+"registration", {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify( {
            "fullname": this.state.fullname,
            "username": this.state.username,
            "email": this.state.email,
            "password": this.state.password,
            "confirm_password": this.state.confirm_password,
            "latitude" : "0",
            "longitude": "0",
            "country": "0",
          } )
          })
          .then((response) =>  response.json())  
          .then((responseJson) => {

            let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseJson));

            if (jsonObj.status=="true") {          
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Tabs');
            } 
             else {
                  alert(jsonObj.message);
                }               
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
          });
  }

  navigateSIGNIN = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Signin'); 
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View >
      <MyStatusBar backgroundColor={colors.transColor} barStyle="light-content" />
      <View>
        <ImageBackground  style={styles.top_img}  source={require('../../assets/imgs/bg2.png')}>

          <View style={styles.logoimg_signup}>
            <Image style={styles.logo_text_img} source={require('../../assets/imgs/logo_text.png')}></Image>
          </View>

      <View style={styles.signView}>

          <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
          placeholder="USERNAME"
          placeholderTextColor= {colors.dividerColor}
          onChangeText={ username => this.setState({username}) }
          />

           <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
          placeholder="FULL NAME"
          placeholderTextColor= {colors.dividerColor}
          onChangeText={ fullname => this.setState({fullname}) }
          />

           <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
          placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"
          placeholderTextColor= {colors.dividerColor}
          onChangeText={ email => this.setState({email}) }
          />

          <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
          placeholder="PASSWORD"
          placeholderTextColor= {colors.dividerColor}
          secureTextEntry password={true}
          onChangeText={ password => this.setState({password}) }
          />

           <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
          placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD"
          placeholderTextColor= {colors.dividerColor}
          secureTextEntry password={true}
          onChangeText={ confirm_password => this.setState({confirm_password}) }
          />

          <Text style={styles.dating_nearby}>I AGREE WITH TERMS & CONDITIONS</Text>


              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonSignin} onPress={ this.signupCall }>
                <Text style={styles.sign_btns_txt} >SIGN UP</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>


          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.facebookButton} onPress={() => navigate('Tabs')}>
              <Text style={styles.social_sign_btns_txt}>SIGN UP WITH FACEBOOK</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.googleButton} onPress={() => navigate('Tabs')}>
              <Text style={styles.social_sign_btns_txt}>SIGN UP WITH GOOGLE</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Text style={styles.bottomTextLoginSignFor} 
             onPress={ this.navigateSIGNIN  }
              >
              ALREADY HAVE ACCOUNT? 
                <Text style={{color: colors.primaryColor}}> SIGNIN NOW
          </Text>
          </Text>

        </ImageBackground>
      </View>

    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Styles**

```
    signView: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: '80%',
      borderRadius: 5,
      padding:10,
      backgroundColor: colors.whiteColor,
      shadowColor: colors.blackColor,
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 5,
      elevation: 5,
    },
 inputBox:{
      textAlign: 'center', 
      width: '80%',
      padding: 5,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
      marginTop: 10,
      fontSize: 16,
      color: colors.blackColor,
    },
 dating_nearby: {
      height:16,
      textAlign: 'center', 
      marginTop:20,
      marginBottom:10,
      color: colors.subTextColor,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
    },
    buttonSignin:{
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      height: 45, 
      width: '65%',
      borderRadius: 35,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
      color: colors.whiteColor,
      backgroundColor: colors.leftColor,
      shadowColor: colors.blackColor,
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 5,
      elevation: 3,
    },
 sign_btns_txt: { 
      color: colors.whiteColor,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
    },
    facebookButton:{
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      height: 45, 
      width: '50%',
      marginTop: 20,
      borderRadius: 35,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
      color: colors.whiteColor,
      backgroundColor: colors.facebookColor,
      shadowColor: colors.blackColor,
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 5,
      elevation: 3,
    },
    googleButton:{
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      height: 45, 
      width: '50%',
      marginTop: 10,
      borderRadius: 35,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
      color: colors.whiteColor,
      backgroundColor: colors.googleColor,
      shadowColor: colors.blackColor,
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 5,
      elevation: 3,
    },
social_sign_btns_txt: {
      color: colors.whiteColor,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
    },
 bottomTextLoginSignFor: {
      height:16,
      textAlign: 'center', 
      marginTop:20,
      marginBottom:20,
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center',
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      fontFamily: Fonts.MontserratR,
      color: colors.subTextColor,
      fontSize: 12,
    },
```

Comment: I believe there is probably an overlap between one of the TouchableOpacity with the Text container. Try replacing wrapping the Sign In Text with an TouchableWithoutFeedback, and move the onPress handler away from the Text component

Comment: I did try that. I placed my Sign in Text in a TouchableOpacity and then it also worked fine. But the major issue is that I'm not facing this problem every time, it's just once in a while. So now I don't know what's the real issue here.

Comment: Can you add all styles as well?

Comment: @dentemm I don't think it would be a styles issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the react-native docs:

> The `Text` element is special relative to layout: everything inside is no longer using the flexbox layout but using text layout. This means that elements inside of a  are no longer rectangles, but wrap when they see the end of the line.`

So I believe there is some sort of overlap between your buttons and the Text component. You can try adding backgroundcolor to all buttons to visually check any overlap.

Comment: I've updated my question with styles. Can you please check it. :)

Comment: I am not sure, but the culprit is most likely  `position: 'absolute'`. There is a known problem for Android where touch events aren't always passed to an absolutely positioned view, if the touch area is outside of the container element.

Comment: Well, I changed the `position: 'absoulte'` and instead used marginTop: 80. For now this problem is not occurring, but let's hope I don't see it again.

Comment: I am sure it is solved by removing the absolute position. And on iOS it will always work, even with the absolute position.

Comment: @ShubhamBisht Sorry I cannot help you with that one, I have no experience with camera usage for react-native